# yarn linking and using a typescript module directly

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

In an attempt to organize some code I extracted a bunch of TypeScript React components into their own npm module that is scoped with my organization name then yarn linked back into the original codebase.

In my original code base I now have:

```
import { Title } from '@foo/ui'
```

Typescript is giving me this error `Cannot find module '@foo/ui' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

Now I can see my module symlinked in my original repo `node_modules` folder no problem.

I do not have a separate typings file - everything is in each react module - I attempted to create a semi empty typings file nonetheless though it's a bit unclear to me how one uses scoped packages. I have:

```
/
   @types
     @foo
        ui.d.ts
     index.d.ts
```

Both d.ts files have just a basic entry:

```
declare module '@foo/ui'
```

Now key to this is Id like to use the TypeScript files in my `@foo/ui` directly without generating js files (is that possible? the point of this is to have easy development side by side as the `ui` module is in the works`.  I am relatively new to TS so clearly missing something here - adding scopes and yarn links doesn't help!

Can someone shed some light as to how I can resolve this? Ideally with direct usage of the TS files.

Comment: I'm having the exact same challenge - did you manage to come up with a solution?